# How to install elementary OS 5 on prepared before ext4 filesystem with additional parameters?

Tags: system-installation, release-juno

I have partitioned and prepared an `ext4` file system with additional needed parameters. I need to install elementary OS 5 JUNO on this formatted partition. But the elementary OS installer won't let me choose this partition for install. elementary OS Automated install tool is too stupid for this - can't mount root on prepared before ext4. Can you help me with installing it?

Ext4 filesystem parameters:

```
mkfs.ext4 -O ^has_journal -E stride=1,stripe-width=512 -b 4096 -L Linux  /dev/sdb1
```

EDIT: There are special parameters I don't want to change but This installer wants to change them when I choose partition for installing. It has to be `ext4` without journaling and a special sride and strap. But there's only an arbitrary option for ext4 with journaling and some not disclosed stride and strap parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Please chose **Something else** in the installation process when it asks you where to install the OS. The options are like,

> - Erase the disk and install
> - Remove your current OS and install elementary OS
> - Something else

After choosing **something else**, you will be able to select the partition you want to install.

Comment: Of course I'm using only "something else option"... But there's no option to select my existing ext partition and mount root. There is simply no option there. I can only click change and edit partition and use it as the list says (i.e. ext4 with journaling)

Comment: I think you didn't noticed my filesystem parameters  - there are special parameters I don't wan't to change but This installer wants to change them when I choose partition for installing. It has to be ext4 without journaling and special sride and strap. But theres only arbitrary option for ext4 with journaling and some not disclosed  stride and strap parameters